# Wlan access point c#, получение локальных Ip-адресов подключенных пользователей

Tags: c#, wlan

Создаю на ноутбуке точку доступа wlan (команда в командной строке netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=AP key=12345678). Как с помощью средств C# получить список локальных ip-адресов пользователей, подключенных к данной точке ? В дальнейшем необходимо будет реализовать передачу сообщений по UDP протоколу.